# Analyzing $ Mongod Sever start-up data after [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017

Tags: mongodb

what does the data after  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017 mean?

[image: $mongod Server data]

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running as process in foreground, you are seeing this log. It is essentially looking for someone to connect to it. You can open another shell/terminal/command prompt and connect to this. Or if you want to run it in background, you can use fork -f flag.

Comment: how do you go about doing the first option?

Comment: Add the `--fork` flag when calling `mongod`. Like `mongod --fork <REST OF THE OPTIONS>`